# Write the output from your Instrument class methods to a text file that a user entered from the command line arguments

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm taking Java Introductory Programming class and currently i'm working on a final project. The assignment description can be found here [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19699/school-project-critique)

I'm having hard time with accomplishing this "Write the output from your Instrument class methods to a text file that a user entered from the command line arguments (e.g. java Mynamep3tst myfilename.txt)." Here's some of my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String outputFile = "";
    if (0 < args.length) {
         outputFile = args[0];
         System.out.println("This program will write output to this file: " + outputFile + "\n");

     try {

        File file = new File(outputFile);

       PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

        output.println("hello"); //to check if ir prints anything

        Violin[] simpleViolin = new Violin[5];

   //Create 5 violin objects
    for (int i = 0; i < simpleViolin.length; i++){
        simpleViolin[i] = new Violin();
    }

    output.println("\nLet's tune " + Violin.getNumberOfViolins() + " violins.");
    for(int i = 0; i < simpleViolin.length; i++){
        output.print(i + 1);
        simpleViolin[i].tuneOn();
    }

   output.println("\nNow let's start playing " + Violin.getNumberOfViolins() + " violins.");
   for(int i = 0; i < simpleViolin.length; i++){
        output.print(i + 1);
        simpleViolin[i].startPlaying();
    }

    output.println("\nIt looks like " + Violin.getNumberOfViolins() + " violins have untuned.");
    for(int i = 0; i < simpleViolin.length; i++){
        output.print(i + 1);
        simpleViolin[i].tuneOff();
    }

    output.println("\nThis music is terrible! Let's stop it!");
    for(int i = 0; i < simpleViolin.length; i++){
        output.print(i + 1);
        simpleViolin[i].stopPlaying();
    }

        output.close();

    }

    catch (IOException io){

        System.out.println("Sorry that file is not found " + io);

    }
  }//end if

   }//end main

}//end Test

class Violin{
private final int numberOfStrings = 4;
private final char[] stringNames = {'E', 'A', 'D', 'G'};
private boolean isTuned = false;
private boolean isPlaying = false;
private static int numberOfViolins = 0;
private PrintWriter output;

public Violin(){
    numberOfViolins++;
}

public void startPlaying() {
    isPlaying = true;
    System.out.println(" violin is now playing.");
}

public void stopPlaying() {
    isPlaying = false;
    System.out.println(" violin has stopped playing.");
}

public void tuneOn() {
    isTuned = true;
    System.out.println(" violin is now tuned.");
}

public void tuneOff() {
    isTuned = false;
    System.out.println(" violin is untuned.");
} 

static int getNumberOfViolins(){
    return numberOfViolins;
}
}//end class Violin
```

So my question is how do I make my Violin class methods to print to a user specified file?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your Violin object you can pass the output as a reference on the constructor so inside the violin you will use output instead of System.out.println.

Change the Violoin constructor to:

```
public Violin (PrintStream output){
    this.output = output;
}
```

And then just use the outpu inside the violin.

Comment: Thanks! That worked in NetBeans like a charm. However, when I put my class Violin in a separate file and try to compile my Test.java through Command Prompt it gives me an error: constructor Violin in class Violin cannot be applied to given types. Basically i'm passing an argument to a constructor that does not requires arguments.

Comment: Did you made the class public?

Comment: Can you post the full compiler message?

Comment: Constructor Violin in class Violin cannot be applied to given types:
simpleViolin[i] = new Violin(output);
required: no argument
found: PrintWriter //im using PrintWriter instead of PrintStream
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: It looks to me that you have an old version compiled on your system. But I would like to make sure that you remove the inner Violin class from the original file, did you?

Comment: I just received a reply form a professor regarding this project. There should be 2 java files. Project.java with classes and ProjectTest.java with main() method. Here’s what I have:
Project. Java file
public class Project{
 static class Violin{}
 static class guitar{}
}
ProjectTest.java file
Public class ProjectTest extends Project{}
With System.out.print everything works. Once I pass output to constructors and change all outputs to output.print I get that same error - actual and formal argument lists differ in length